# increment numbers in an array until they are all equal

Tags: java, arrays, performance, increment

The goal of this program is to make all numbers in an array the same. You have to increment all values in the array except for one each time. Then the program will print out the minimum number of steps it would take to make all the numbers the same. I have what I believe is a working solution I just want to make it more efficient, does any one have any ideas? In the following code the user enters the initial values for the numbers into the array and then calculates the amount of steps required

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException 
{
counter=0;
         size=sc.nextInt();
         input= new int[size];
        for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
        {
            input[k]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        while(!isAllEqual(input))
        {
            Arrays.sort(input);
            for(int k=0; k<input.length-1; k++)
            {
                input[k]++;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        pw.println(counter);

public static boolean isAllEqual(int[] a){
    for(int i=1; i<a.length; i++){
        if(a[0] != a[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: In questions about algorithms, you should omit dealing with user input. Just make a function that takes the needed values as parameters, it's more readable that way.

Comment: Also, `isAllEqual()` is a major performance hit, and sorting is also needless. Just find the maximum value once, and increment up to that - you don't need to check whether you've satisfied the condition if you know your algorithm will get there.

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? Why not loop through the array to find the biggest and smallest numbers, then set every slot in the arra to the biggest number. Steps is biggest - smallest.

Comment: The trick is you have to increment all the numbers in the array except one, it's not so simple I think.

Comment: @sjr - Actually, if you're going to actually increment (which I'm not sure you need to do), then you need to avoid incrementing _all_ entries that are already at the maximum.

Comment: well, you can't do that because the problem says you must increment all but one :)

Comment: @sjr - Ah. Good point! If that's what OP actually needs, then this is a truly interesting problem. It's not just a matter of counting, but of discovering a strategy for which number to not increment at each step. If that's what OP wants, then my answer is, of course, wrong. It's not immediately obvious to me that there's always a solution.

Comment: yes that what I was trying to say. Its a matter of determining what to increment. I think you increment all number except for the largest one. If two numbers are both the largest then you just pick one of them to increment since you are only aloud to not increment one number.

Comment: Method isAllEqual() can return true?

Comment: yeah it can i just forgot to coppy that part @user1929959 ill put it in

Answer (score 7):

It might be easier to wrap your head around this if you change the step into something simpler. If we're only talking about equality between the values (i.e. relative, not absolute values), incrementing and decrementing *all* of the values at once makes no difference. If we change our step to "increment all but one, then decrement every value by one", we can see that incrementing all but one is equivalent to decrementing a single value.

Can you figure out the number of steps to make the values equal if the step is "decrement one value"? It should involve looping through the array two times at max, and no sorting.

Comment: Nice insight. It makes the calculation (as well as the existence of a solution) relatively obvious.

Answer (score 4):

MAJOR EDIT AS I MISREAD THE QUESTION

Scan through the list just once to find the minimum value in the list and the total of adding all the values together.

Once you have these two values, the number of required increments is:

[total of all the values] - [number of items in list] * [minimum value]

In code:

```
public static int numberOfSteps(int[] a) {
    if( a.length==0 ) return 0;

    int min= a[0];
    int total = a[0];
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++) {
        if( a[i] < min ) min = a[i];
        total += a[i];
    }

    return total - a.length * min;
}
```

This works because (as Matti Virkkunen pointed out) the number of decrements for each item is `(a[i] - min )` so for the entire list it is `sum(a[i]-min)` which we can expand to `sum(a[i]-(length*min)`.

The corresponding increments would be at each step to increment everything except the right most item which is equal to the maximum. For example:

Initial state = (0,1,1,1)
 1. increment everything except a[3] --> (1,2,2,1)
 2. increment everything except a[2] --> (2,3,2,2)
 3. increment everything except a[1] --> (3,3,3,3) : solution in three steps = (1+1+1) - (4 * 0)

and again, initial state of (1,2,3,3)

1. increment everything except a[3] --> (2,3,4,3)
2. increment everything except a[2] --> (3,4,4,4)
3. increment everything except a[3] --> (4,5,5,4)
4. increment everything except a[2] --> (5,6,5,5)
5. increment everything except a[1] --> (6,6,6,6) : solution in five steps = (1+2+3+3) - (4 * 1)

Comment: I don't think your formula works for the list (0, 1, 1, 1). The formula says the number of increments should be 4*1 - 3 = 1, but there's no single step that solves the problem.

Comment: Ah - didn't think of duplicated maxima :-(

Comment: @SimonG. If the increment changes to other increments like 2, 5 how does this change?